# 配列探索について

Tags: python, python3

```
n, m = map(int,input().split())
test_list = []
a1_list = []
for _ in range(n):
    a1, b1 = map(int,input().split())
    a1_list.append(a1)
    test_point = a1-(b1*5)
    if test_point >= m:
        test_list.append(test_point)
    else:
        test_list.append('ng')

test_list.insert(0, 'dummy')

print(test_list)
```

上記のソースコード作成

入力値

```
 5 25
 80 11
 20 1
 50 2
 70 0
 25 1
```

出力値

```
['dummy', 25, 'ng', 40, 70, 'ng']
```

このような結果になります。

次に、出力値の数値のみ探索する場合、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

考えてる出力結果

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

探索値を指定した出力は出来るのですが、配列内の数値のみを探索することが分からなく、知ってる方いらっしゃいましたらご協力をお願い致します。

Comment: `print([i for i, v in enumerate(test_list) if type(v) == int])`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。すごく助かりました！今後の参考にします！